# How do I fix ugly boot screen when using Nvidia drivers Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: boot, nvidia, graphics, suspend

I have recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit.

It was, by default, using the Nouveau display driver, however, this caused suspend to fail. I installed a proprietary driver which resolved that issue but created an ugly low res boot screen.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution that worked for me. (for those who have this common issue)

Run in Terminal

1. `sudo apt-get install v86d`
2. `gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`
3. Replace Line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

   New Line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=1920x1080-24,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap"`
4. Replace Line: `#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480`

   New Line: `#GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080`
5. Save & Close
6. `gksu gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/modules`
7. Add Line: `uvesafb mode_option=1920x1080-24 mtrr=3 scroll=ywrap`
8. Save & Close
9. `sudo update-grub2`
10. `sudo update-initramfs -u`

Comment: In #8, should you still include the "options" keyword before the line in the uvesafb.conf file?  From Archlinux: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uvesafb#Configure_uvesafb

Comment: @elikakohen It works without "options" in the modules file. So, no, options is apparently only for uvesafb.conf.

Comment: @pst007x so ... I ended up hacking my 9800GT with a custom vesa mode, (in exchange the 1600x1200 setting) -- AND, I also managed to get uvesafb to work.  I decided to mod my video card BIOS since another card was already on the way.  Thanks!

Comment: Does not work for me with NVidia drivers in Linux Mint 18.1. Resolution is fine with Noveau drivers however. Any other solution?